# Discovering all attributes of a AWS DynamoDB table programmatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I know that this can be done with a full table scan & inspecting all records for the presence of attributes. Is there a less painful way ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.  This is one of the trade-offs of DynamoDB.

If there was a way to do this, then storing a new item with a new attribute would have to update something else, somewhere else, that remembered all of the attributes that were present in the table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, given the presence of two kind of indexes and various attributes being projected all around, I would not expect the maintenance of a list of all attributes to be expensive.

Comment: That's a good point, this is something that they might provide as configurable on a table, like another index.  The attributes that get projected around currently are entirely optional.  If you have a table with no range key and no indexes, there are no indexes, which is great for scaling.

Comment: DynamoDB tables don't need to be consistent in terms of columns stored, so this would make discovery of attributes inconsistent (e.g. you could store a person details and address information in the same table if you like).